# Lambda Expression definition (pedant )?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, lambda

By just briefing a book (leading one)  , one thing caught my eyes - the lambda expression definition   :

> A lambda expression is an unnamed method written in place of a
>   delegate instance.

*in place of delegate instance ???*

A delegate instance is an *object* that refers-to/encapsulate  target method/s :

In the following sample The right side(where the lambda expression would be) is not a delegate instance. it is a method.

`TransformerDelegate t = SquareMethod;`

So the definition should have been corrected-to/mention  :

> lambda expression are unnamed method written in place of a method(!)
>   being referenced by delegate variable.

```
TransformerDelegate sqr = x => x * x;
                              ^
                              |
               ---------------+
               |

            this is the location for method/anonymous methods.
```

do you see what I mean ? Am I right?

p.s. I *did* understand the msdn's one : ( but want to see if the book had made a mistake)

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain
>   expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or
>   expression tree types.

Comment: You have a sharp eye for this sort of subtle issue; you are correct that the phrasing is inelegant and inexact, even if it gets the right idea across. If you read technical books closely you will very quickly find lots of these sorts of issues; even experienced writers confuse "object" with "variable", for instance. The only book I have edited that used technical terms correctly pretty much every time was of course _C# in Depth_. :-)

Comment: Pedantry: in the statement `TransformerDelegate t = SquareMethod;`, SquareMethod is not a method, it is a *method group*.

Comment: @phoog why do you say it is a method group ? the TransformerDelegate  _type_ has a strict definition . for example : `public delegate int TransformerDelegate (int a)` it will only execute for ints. Did you mean that it can be execute with less derived types ? but what is less _derived_ than int ?

Comment: Eric Lippert will probably correct me here but I think @phoog means that the name SquareMethod can be several overloaded methods and is therefore called a MethodGroup even if it just one method in this case. (Only one of the overloaded methods can match the delegate signature so only one is added to the delegate)

Comment: @adrianm is correct.  Royi, I say it is a method group because that's what the C# spec calls it (see section 6.1.12 of the MS specification).  The TransformerDelegate type is not the method group, however.  The method group is a source code concept, relevant only to the compiler.  So, for that matter, is a lambda expression.  The compiler translates these source code elements into IL code that instantiates delegate instances (or, in some cases, expression tree instances).  There's no "lambda expression" object (nor a "method group" object) in memory at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of a lambda expression *is* a delegate instance.

So the book is probably referring to code like:

```
MySquareDelegate f1 = x => x * x;
MySquareDelegate f2 = new MySquareDelegate(MySquareMethod);
MySquareDelegate f3 = MySquareMethod;  // just shorthand for the previous line
```

It is tricky stuff to explain in 1 sentence, your own version

> lambda expression are unnamed method written in place of a method(!) being referenced by delegate variable.

is talking about "a method instead of a method", the original about "a method instead of a delegate instance" where the method is implicitly converted to a delegate instance. Both seem incomplete at least.

A definition of a lambda should also include that it is an *inline* method.

Comment: +1 makes sense. in my head it was `MySquareDelegate f2 = MySquareMethod` and in the right side is just a method. but the old fashioned way( using new() ) clarified things. thanks . so the book is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers miss the fact that lambda expressions do not necessarily represent methods.  Sometimes, they represent expression trees.

The compiler implicitly converts lambda expressions to one type of object or the other, depending on context.

To specify a method, you need to specify parameters and a body.  In a lambda expression, these are separated by `=>`.  Examples:

```
    ()     => 4;               //empty parameter list
    x      => x.ToString();    //one parameter
    (a, b) => a.Equals(b);     //two parameters
//  ^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  |                    |
//  parameter list       body
```

These lambda expressions can be converted to `Func<int>`, `Func<object, string>`, and `Func<object, object, bool>` respectively.  The could also be converted to `Expression<Func<int>>`, `Expression<Func<object, string>>`, and `Expression<Func<object, object, bool>>` respectively.

An anonymous method:

```
delegate (object p, object q) { return string.Concat(p, q); }
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//       parameter list       body
```

Here are two examples of lambda conversion:

```
Func<object, object, bool> aDelegate = (o1, o2) => object.Equals(o1, o2);
Expression<Func<object, object, bool>> anExpressionTree = (o1, o2) => object.Equals(o1, o2);
```

In method group conversion, the parameters and method body are specified by overload resolution.  To simplify a bit, the compiler looks at the methods with the indicated name and chooses the correct overload based on the context.  For example, consider these overloads of SquareMethod:

```
int SquareMethod(int a) { return a * a; }
double SquareMethod(double a) { return a * a; }
```

These statements involve method group conversion and overload resolution:

```
Func<int, int> squareAnInt = SquareMethod;
Func<double, double> squareADouble = SquareMethod;
```

Finally, statement lambdas cannot be translated to expression trees:

```
Action<object> anAction = o => { Console.WriteLine(o); };
Func<object, int> aFunc = o =>
    {
        var s = (o ?? "").ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        return s.Length;
    };
```

The C# language specification (somewhat confusingly) uses the term "anonymous function" to cover both lambda expressions and anonymous methods.  Anonymous functions can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type, and so can method groups.  Therefore, if we have a delegate type called `DelegateType`, and a declaration/assignment like this:

```
DelegateType d = [something];
```

Then `[something]` can be a method group or an anonymous function.  In other words, it can be a method group, an anonymous method or a lambda expression.

So, your correction to the book's text would be better to say "in place of a method group", but I would say

> A lambda expression is an unnamed method that, like a named method group, can be used to create a delegate instance.

I might also add

> In some cases, a lambda expression can be used to create an expression tree rather than a delegate instance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a delegate is nothing but an **object** that knows how to call a specific method.  So a delegate **instance** literally acts as a delegate for the caller: the caller invokes the delegate, and then the delegate calls the target method.

Comment: "The object is built by the compiler" kind of glosses over the finer points, doesn't it?  The object is built at run time, not compile time.